# create static variable to hold Validator in Laravel

Tags: php, static, laravel, laravel-4

I created a library with a 'validate' function that I use to validate my fields, within that function the rules are automatically retrieved from a config location. To keep things clean I don't this 'validate' function to return the validator object instead I prefer doing like so and would like to know if this is ok to do? How else would you do this?

// mycontroller

```
if(!My_val::validate($input))
  return $this->response(My_val::$val->messages()->first());
```

// my library

```
class My_val {

  public static $val;

  public function __construct() {
    $val= null;
  }

public static function validate($data) {
    // commented out section ---- here the rules are extracted from a config file
    self::$val= Validator::make($data);
    return self::$val->passes();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find amazing tutorials by Jeffrey Way at TutsPlus.
Can't be done better, imho.

Validating with models & event listeners
https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validating-with-models-and-event-listeners/

Validation services
https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validation-services/